# How do you append a variable into a 2D array?

Tags: python, arrays

I would like to append an input into a specific position in a 2D array. The task is to input my own data to replace a position in the array.

```
#Array
Days = ["Mon 1","Tue 1","Wed 1","Thu 1","Fri 1",
        "Mon 2","Tue 2","Wed 2","Thu 2","Fri 2",
        "Mon 3","Tue 3","Wed 3" ,"Thu 3","Fri 3",
        "Mon 4","Tue 4","Wed 4","Thu 4","Fri 4"]

Route = ["Bus A","Bus B","Bus C","Bus D","Bus E","Bus F"]
            #The array in each bus is (Mon 1 - Fri 4 in each bus)
BusData = [[0,0,0,2,2,4,0,3,4,-2,-5,0,0,3,4,-1,8,1,1,-2],          #Bus A
            [0,1,0,0,1,2,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,2,0,0,1,0,0],             #Bus B
            [2,0,-1,-1,-2,-2,-3,-1,0,0,-2,0,1,1,1,1,-1,-1,2,-1],   #Bus C
            [1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,2,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],           #Bus D
            [-1,-1,-1,-2,-4,-10,-2,0,0,0,0,1,2,-3,1,1,3,-1,0,0],   #Bus E
            [0,-5,-5,-5,-4,-3,-5,0,0,0,0,-2,-3,1,1,1,0,0,-2,-5]]   #Bus F
```

For example, I have inputted a day and route, and trying to use the index position to place it in the array.

I tried to do a solution like this:

```
        #Input values in array
    for i in Route:    #Finding index of input in array 
        if Bus == i:
            RoutePos = Route.index(i)

    for i in Days:   #Finding index of input in array
        if Day == i:
            DayPos = Days.index(i)


    DataPos = BusData[RoutePos][DayPos]
    BusData.append(DataPos)

    print(BusData)
```

If anyone wants me to elaborate on the question, let me know

Comment: Where is `Bus` and `Day` coming from? Also why `append` if you are trying to *replace* the data? There seems to be some fundamental confusion from the way you are coding it. How are you getting your inputs?

Comment: What result do you expect?  This appends an integer to the end of your 2D list, as if it were the one and only entry for Bus G.

Comment: @Idlehands yes I am trying to replace it and inputs are done before

Answer (score 1):

You've combined several half solutions; this isn't needed.  You simply look up the route and day indices:

```
route_pos = Route.index(Bus)
day_pos = Days.index(Day)
BusData.append(BusData[route_pos][day_pos]
```

However, I'm not at all sure this is what you want.  This appends a single integer to the 2D list, such as:

```
[[0,0,0,2,2,4,0,3,4,-2,-5,0,0,3,4,-1,8,1,1,-2],         #Bus A
 [0,1,0,0,1,2,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,2,0,0,1,0,0],             #Bus B
 [2,0,-1,-1,-2,-2,-3,-1,0,0,-2,0,1,1,1,1,-1,-1,2,-1],   #Bus C
 [1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,2,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],           #Bus D
 [-1,-1,-1,-2,-4,-10,-2,0,0,0,0,1,2,-3,1,1,3,-1,0,0],   #Bus E
 [0,-5,-5,-5,-4,-3,-5,0,0,0,0,-2,-3,1,1,1,0,0,-2,-5],   #Bus F
 2   # New element
]
```

Comment: I would assume the final answer is somewhere close to `BusData[route_pos][day_pos] = some_data`, but the question is *how* is `some_data` being received and what is `Bus/Day`.

Answer (score 0):

First off python uses lists not arrays.
To append to a list use the .append function 
eg:

```
List_name.append(Insert_data_to_append_here)
```

In your case:

```
BusData.append(BusData[route_pos][day_pos])
```

instead of:

```
DataPos = BusData[RoutePos][DayPos]
BusData.append(DataPos)
```

so it is combined into one line as it makes it cleaner.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this is appropriate, because perhaps you need your data in list form. But if not, Pandas would make this trivial.

```
import pandas as pd
# the fourth row had an extra digit, I deleted a zero
df = pd.DataFrame(data=BusData, index=Route, columns=Days)

df=df.T

df.loc['Mon 1', 'Bus B'] = 25
df.loc['Wed 1'] = 100
df.loc[:,'Bus F'] = 999

df

         Bus A   Bus B  Bus C   Bus D    Bus E     Bus F
Mon 1      0       25      2       1       -1       999
Tue 1      0       1       0       0       -1       999
Wed 1      100     100     100     100     100      999
Thu 1      2       0       -1      0       -2       999
Fri 1      2       1       -2      0       -4       999
Mon 2      4       2       -2      0       -10      999
Tue 2      0       0       -3      0       -2       999
Wed 2      3       0       -1      0       0        999
Thu 2      4       0       0       0       0        999
Fri 2      -2      0       0       0       0        999
Mon 3      -5      1       -2      2       0        999
Tue 3      0       0       0       0       1        999
Wed 3      0       0       1       0       2        999
Thu 3      3       0       1       0       -3       999
Fri 3      4       2       1       0       1        999
Mon 4      -1      0       1       0       1        999
Tue 4      8       0       -1      0       3        999
Wed 4      1       1       -1      0       -1       999
Thu 4      1       0       2       0       0        999
Fri 4      -2      0       -1      0       0        999
```

Comment: yeah it works but isnt what im looking for. Would use in the furture thou!

Answer (score 0):

Since it's unclear what exactly you are looking for, this answer assumes the following three conditions based on your clarification so far:

1. `Bus` is a string input of *exact match* within `Route`,
2. `Day` is a string input of *exact match* within `Days`,
3. `BusData` is sorted in the *same order* of `Route` and `Days`.

Then it's as simple as this:

```
route_pos = Route.index(Bus)
day_pos = Days.index(Day)
BusData[route_pos][day_pos] == some_data_to_replace
```

Where `some_data_to_replace` is the route information you want to replace for that specific `Bus` and `Day`.

For example:

```
Bus = input("Enter the exact bus info: ")                 # e.g. "Bus C"
Day = input("Enter the exact day info: ")                 # e.g. "Mon 2"
Data = int(input("Enter the route info to replace: "))     # e.g. 99

route_pos = Route.index(Bus)                              # position 2
day_pos = Days.index(Day)                                 # position 5 
BusData[route_pos][day_pos] == some_data_to_replace       # "row" 2, "col" 5 is replaced

BusData

# [[0,0,0,2,2,4,0,3,4,-2,-5,0,0,3,4,-1,8,1,1,-2],         # Bus A
#  [0,1,0,0,1,2,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,2,0,0,1,0,0],             # Bus B
#  [2,0,-1,-1,-2,99,-3,-1,0,0,-2,0,1,1,1,1,-1,-1,2,-1],   # Bus C (pos 2) Mon 1 (pos 5) is replaced
#  [1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,2,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],           # Bus D
#  [-1,-1,-1,-2,-4,-10,-2,0,0,0,0,1,2,-3,1,1,3,-1,0,0],   # Bus E
#  [0,-5,-5,-5,-4,-3,-5,0,0,0,0,-2,-3,1,1,1,0,0,-2,-5]]   # Bus F
```